# wp_enqueue_scripts fail to add custom stylesheet

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$custom_style = 'css/pre/custom-styles.css';
function custom_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'aps-custom-style', APS_URL .$custom_style, APS_VER );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_stylesheet' );
```

APS_URL is the url of directory.

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it to the function:

```
$custom_style = 'css/pre/custom-styles.css';
function custom_stylesheet($custom_style) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'aps-custom-style', APS_URL .$custom_style, APS_VER );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_stylesheet' );
```

or declare it [global](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions):

```
$custom_style = 'css/pre/custom-styles.css';
function custom_stylesheet() {
    global $custom_style;
    wp_enqueue_style( 'aps-custom-style', APS_URL .$custom_style, APS_VER );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_stylesheet' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
wp_enqueue_style( string $handle, string $src = '', array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

You should pass an array as $deps argument  first, before $vers argument.